# Solving memory leak in SearchKit CoreService

Tags: swift, macos, memory-leaks, core-services

I have been working on a project using Apple's [SearchKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/search_kit?language=objc). But I recently found a memory leak through instruments, which points to the SearchKit. Like the code below

```
guard
    let document = SKDocumentCreateWithURL(fileURL)?.takeRetainedValue()
else { return false }
defer { SKIndexFlush(indexFile) }
// Both SKIndexAddDocumentWithText and SKIndexAddDocument are builtin SearchKit
let addMethod: documentAddFunc = type == .nameOnly ? SKIndexAddDocumentWithText : SKIndexAddDocument
let textContent: CFString? = type == .nameOnly ? (fileName + " \(additionalNote)") as CFString : nil
return addMethod(indexFile, document, textContent, true)/* The line where instrument suggests the memory leak happened*/
```

Some explanations here: the two functions may be assigned to `addMethod` are both built in functions from SearchKit. `indexFile` is SKIndex type. `document` is created on the top of the picture, which should be correct.

So is this a bug on Apple's side or it's my problem to trigger this memory leak? Is there anything I can do to avoid or fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you posting, deleting and then posting again pretty much the same topic?

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted that one before, then I kinda figured out how to solve it. Then I delete it, cuz I figured the problem is solved. After a while, I realize the problem is still there... And I could not find the previous post again, so I posted another one

Comment: I see.  That's no problem.  I think you can find your deleted topic under questions if you go to your Activity.